# VBA - Type mismatch on declaration of Excel.Range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to declare a range of cells as an Excel.Range variable in the BeforeSave() event of  my excel workbook. 
The background is, that the values in this range are mandatory inputs and I want to validate that they are all filled on saving.

If I want to execute the function I get the error message

`Runtime Error "13": Type Mismatch`

Here's the code I tried.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim r1 As Range
    Set r1 = Range("G11:G14")

        If Cells(10, 1).Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "Cell requires user input", vbInformation, "Please filled up the mandatory cells"
            Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf r1.Value = "" Then // runtime error "13": Type Mismatch
            MsgBox "Please make sure you had filled in all the Questionnire Answers.", vbInformation, "Missing Answer"
            Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Cancel = False
End Sub
```

I am relatively new to VBA so please feel free to point out my mistake.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you debug the code, to check which line is causing the error? 
OR share your **detailed-error text** in a block

Comment: Is you code in a Worksheet or a standard Module ?

Comment: It's under 'ThisWorkbook'. The whole work book only has one sheet.

Comment: You are testing if `r1.Value = ""` but `r1` is set as `Range("G11:G14")` and therefore has multiple values. Do you want to test the value of each of `G11`, `G12`, `G13` and `G14`?

Comment: Yes, I want to check cell G11, G12 and so on. Whether each cell is empty or contain value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get this error:

> Runtime Error "13": Type Mismatch

Because `r1` is defined as a `Range` of multiple cells and you cannot check if a multiple-cell `Range` is simply empty string. You need to check each cell in the range.

Try this code - it is a `Function` that checks to see if any cell, in a group of cells, is `""` and returns `True` if that is so:

```
Option Explicit

Function TestMultipleCellsAnyAreEmpty(rng As Range) As Boolean

    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim blnAnyRangeIsEmpty

    blnAnyRangeIsEmpty = False

    For Each rngCell In rng
        If rngCell.Value = "" Then
            blnRangeIsEmpty = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next rngCell

    TestMultipleCellsAreEmpty = blnRangeIsEmpty

End Function
```

Combining this technique with your workbook event you can have this complete code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim r1 As Range
    Set r1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YOUR_SHEET").Range("G11:G14") '<-- specify the worksheet

    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YOUR_SHEET").Cells(10, 1).Value = "" Then '<-- specify the worksheet
        MsgBox "Cell requires user input", vbInformation, "Please filled up the mandatory cells"
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf TestMultipleCellsAnyAreEmpty(r1) Then
        MsgBox "Please make sure you had filled in all the Questionnire Answers.", vbInformation, "Missing Answer"
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Cancel = False

End Sub

Function TestMultipleCellsAnyAreEmpty(rng As Range) As Boolean

    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim blnAnyRangeIsEmpty

    blnAnyRangeIsEmpty = False

    For Each rngCell In rng
        If rngCell.Value = "" Then
            blnRangeIsEmpty = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next rngCell

    TestMultipleCellsAreEmpty = blnRangeIsEmpty

End Function
```

Comment: Hi, will the check occurs beforeSave/beforeClose?  Or I just apply this outside of the `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave`

Comment: @Jeff - see my edit - it incldues the technique in combination with your workbook event code.

Comment: Hi, may I know what does it got to do with cell`(10,1)`? Not`(11,7)`?
After edit it to `(11,7)`, It only checks G11 but not the other cells.

Comment: Your original code has `If Cells(10, 1).Value = "" Then`... so I just replicated that. Your error is because you can't do an `=""` test for a `Range` with multiple cells.

Comment: Alright, Thanks for the explanation. Another problem is that your code only works if all the cell from G11:G14 is empty. If G11 is empty and the rest are filled up. The workbook can still be saved. Can it be checking all the cells within the range?

Comment: @Jeff - I updated the example code. It will now check to see if any of the cells in the Range are empty and return True if so - meaning you get the message box and the save cancels.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's because you need to qualify your range definition to say `Set r1 = ThisWorkbook.Range("G11:G14")`. Also, I believe that the `.Value` property of a multi-cell range will return the value in the top leftmost cell.

Comment: Hi, I just tried your suggestion. After change to `Set r1 = ThisWorkbook.Range(G11:G14)` an error appears. `Compile error: Method or data member not found`

Comment: It would need to be `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G11:G14")` but unlikely this is the cause of the error.